# WebRTC in Chrome (JsSIP) and SDP directive "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, sip, sdp

I use the library JsSIP to make SIP calls over WebRTC plataform in Google Chrome web browser. I have to change the SDP directive "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF" in SIP request to "UDP/RTP/AVPF" in JsSIP.js file because the Asterisk server reject calls no encrypted in TLS context and i need the calls no encrypted. But even with the change, the browser continues to send the "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF" in SIP request. Anyone can help me? The WebRTC implementation or Chrome intercepts the SIP request and change to "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF"? Or in some way, this directive is in cache request and needs a clean up? (I already tried to clean the Chrome cache). Or have another explanation to that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to capture SDP under ['sdp'](http://jssip.net/documentation/3.0.x/api/session/#event_sdp) event thrown by jssip and over write with new sdp

```
'sdp': function(evt){
    evt.sdp = your changed sdp
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow unencrypted/unsecure RTP. It always forces SRTP/DTLS encryption.